# Custom Spring Validator Doesn't Get Injected

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-validator

The problem is this:
Using Spring Boot, I have a hibernate entity (Message) and I want to create a custom validator for it.

```
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
        
@Component
public class MessageValidator implements Validator {
@Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return Message.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    ... Do work here ...
    }
}
```

Then, I have a service

```
@Service
public class MessagesService {

    @Autowired
    Validator validator;

    public void doSomething(Message m) {
        Errors e = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(new Object(), "dummy");
        this.validator.validate(m, e);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the call to this.validator.validate(m, e); never makes it to my implementation.

My pom.xml has (amongst others):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

So, am I missing something glaringly obvious here? If I name the validator component and I qualify the reference in the service, it's all good. But I'm expecting the Spring wiring to provide the proper validator for the type of object I call for. Or is this expectation too much?

Answer (score 0):

Problem must be with your Autowiring.

Since you are using interface here, it could autowire the default (one of the implementation provided by Spring) instance.

```
  @Autowired
  Validator validator;
```

Solution:

1. Use `MessageValidator` instead of `Validator`

```
    @Autowired
    MessageValidator validator;
```

OR 2. Use qualified name:

```
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "messageValidator") //note lowercase m
    Validator validator;
```

Comment: That's the thing. I did mention that qualifying my wiring makes it work, but, looking at the documentation and at any samples I could find online, nobody mentions the fact that you need to do any of that. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/reference/html/core.html#validator
AND
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/reference/html/core.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring-inject
AND
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring-inject

Comment: You can put `debug=true` at your application.properties to see all the configured beans. I am seeing `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` being initialized as default bean in my app. So the solution is to use the MessageValidator or Qualifier

Comment: The problem you are facing is not related to the Validator. Its about how spring/spring-boot creates Beans by default/internally and wires them